# login 'authentication failure' by non-root user, can login only by root

Tags: login, authentication, non-root-user

In my CentOS 6.0 system, working since months, suddenly stop authenticating non-root users, in graphical mode.

- I have checked necessary `/etc/pam.d/*` files, but those are unchanged.
- SELinux is disabled.
- I have also tried configuring autologin, but the cursor starts rotating in wait state and nothing is happening beyond that.
- I have also changed Graphical Display Manager from GDM to KDE, but the problem is same.
- The problem is same after creating new user and trying to login with that.
- There also problem login remotely by ssh for the same non-root users.
- I am also getting 'system is going to halt in 1 min' message along with 'authentication failure' message, when entering password for any user.

There is no problem with root user. And there is no problem login to any user from terminal. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some corruption in my file system. I just booted system by inserting rescue disk and then checked file system with `e2fsck`, and restarted the system. This solved my issue.